# Is there a browser add-on to filter Google search results?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons

Is there a way to block specific sites from appearing in Google search? I'm looking for a browser add-on (preferably Google Chrome) - I don't want to create custom search engines or what-not.

---

> This question was a **[Super User Question of the Week](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/question-of-the-week)**.
>   Read the **[blog entry](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/02/21/hate-the-google-search-spam-theres-an-app-for-that/)** for more details or **[contribute to the blog](http://blog.superuser.com/contribute/)** yourself

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<strike>I can't tell if you're kidding or not.</strike>

[Personal Blocklist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef) does exactly what you need, and it was released yesterday.

> The personal blocklist extension will transmit to Google the patterns that you choose to block. When you choose to block or unblock a pattern, the extension will also transmit to Google the URL of the web page on which the blocked or unblocked search results are displayed. You agree that Google may freely use this information to improve our products and services.

[image]

Comment: Seeding @Randolph ;)

Comment: It's 3:21am. This whole question feels very surreal. And I'm typing on an iPhone screen which isn't helping!

Comment: @Randolp it's inspired by: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2218382

Comment: ooo just what the doctor ordered. I would say he's not joking, as I seem to land on a LOT of "content farms" recently myself and have wondered the same.

Comment: In the daylight it makes sense. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No worries @RandolphPotter :)

Comment: This image is a `WIN` :)

Comment: @Manish, I wish I could vote up @Ivo Flipse for putting it in :-)

Comment: This feature is currently a little hidden, but you can still find it here (if you're logged in): https://www.google.com/reviews/t

Answer (score 5):

[Here's a Greasemonkey script:](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/39996)

[image] [image]

Comment: Unfortunately the link in this answer is broken now. Is the userscript available elsewhere?

Comment: Wayback Machine to the rescue! https://web.archive.org/web/20131103204338/http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/39996  This is a very old script now, I would not expect it to work with today's Google Search page.