# Opera: block sites from Google’s web search results?

Tags: browser-addons, opera, blacklist

Google just released a [Chrome extension to block certain sites](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/new-chrome-extension-block-sites-from.html) from its search results. Is there a similar solution for Opera 11?

Comment: Related [Is there a browser addon to filter Google search results ?](http://superuser.com/questions/245959/is-there-a-browser-addon-to-filter-google-search-results)

Comment: I'm also looking for this extension, and preferably with this feature too (from the above Google blog link): "If installed, the extension also sends blocked site information to Google, and we will study the resulting feedback and explore using it as a potential ranking signal for our search results.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet at least. Hopefully Opera will add this functionality, but I doubt it.

Comment: A shame. I've been trying to find a UserJS but haven't even found a repos that is up-to-date.

Comment: @HNoodles Have you had a look at the related question ? There's a GreaseMonkey script which *might* work

Comment: Checked in out, it does not work with Opera.

Answer (score 2):

[Google search results blocker](https://addons.opera.com/en/addons/extensions/details/google-search-results-blocker/1.0/?display=en)

I've also been looking for such an extension but didn't find one.
So I made one.
At the moment it's fairly basic but seems to work.
I'd appreciate any feedback either on the opera extension site or on the [github](https://github.com/dxg/opera-gsblock) page.

In terms of sending blocked search results to google, I'm not sure how much useful data that would provide given how few opera users there are compared to chrome. It would be nice though if blocked results automatically synced through your google account as with the chrome blocklist extension.

I'm also not entirely sure if the opera extension api exposes the features required to do this, but I haven't looked into it much.