# Remove youtube videos from Google search results

Tags: youtube, google-search

Lately, I have been noticing more and more Youtube videos in my Google search results.  These are almost never what I'm looking for.  When conducting a search, is there any way to have Google only return regular webpages by default? (I'm looking to avoid having to type "-site:youtube.com" in every search).

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://superuser.com/questions/245959/

Answer (score -2):

UPDATE:

You can use a Google Chrome Add-on by Google themselves - [Personal Blocklist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef)

Comment: How does that help avoiding having to type "YouTube.com" so it is excluded from the search?